# Execution process in pipeline

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

This code shows nothing(if date.txt does exist):

> date > date.txt | cut < date.txt --delimiter ' ' --fields 1

**Questions:**

- **Why can't we use date.txt if we have redirected stdout in it?**
- ***Is it like cut takes date.txt as input before it getting written/overwritten? Is the command execution sequence is from left to write in a pipeline or all commands get executed simultaneously and just wait for stdin from stdout of previous pipe command?***

[apologies for grammar and terminology mistakes, and

> date |tee date.txt | cut --delimiter ' ' --fields 1

works, it is known.

]

[image]

Comment: You are telling the shell: "Send the standard output of `date` to the file `date.txt` AND ALSO to the standard input of `cut`". You shell doesn't provide any way to express this, so you have to revert to an external program such as `tee` to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 2):

Commands in a pipeline are executed concurrently. So when you write

```
date > date.txt | cut --delimiter '' --fields 1 < date.txt
```

`cut` might try to read from the file before `date` has written to it, and there's nothing to read. There's no need for a pipeline if you're using a file for communication, just write the commands sequentially.

```
date > date.txt 
cut --delimiter '' --fields 1 < date.txt
```